# Typescript React scrolling detection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, scroll

in my React Typescript application that is designed for mobile devices (in browser environment) I have large Button Cards (as shown in picture below). Each of this Cards has "long press" functionality, when user long presses this Card, list of actions in the drawer is displayed. However I am experiencing bad behaviour when user is slowly scrolling on this page and while scrolling he accidentally long press this card drawer is opened. Is there any way to prevent this behaviour? I have tried to detect in my div where user scrolls if user is scrolling and then pass it via React Context to my useLongPress hook but this is not working. Here is my code for scroll detection and for long press functionality:

```
  contentDivRef?.current?.addEventListener(
"scroll",
function () {
  if (timer !== null && !isScrolling) {
    console.log("scroll start");
    setIsScrolling(true);
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
  timer = setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("scroll end");
    setIsScrolling(false);
  }, 250);
},
false
  );
```

and my useLongPress hook, whose event handlers are attached to Card div :

```
      function startPressTimer() {
    isLongPress.current = false;
    timerRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
      isLongPress.current = true;
      console.log(isScrolling);
      onLongPress?.();
    }, 500);
  }

  function handleOnMouseDown() {
    startPressTimer();
  }

  function handleOnMouseUp() {
    clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
  }

  function handleOnTouchStart() {
    console.log("handleOnTouchStart");
    startPressTimer();
  }

  function handleOnTouchEnd() {
    if (action === "longpress") return;
    console.log("handleOnTouchEnd");
    clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
  }
```

Is there by any chance any clearer smarter way to do this? Thank you
[image: Screenshot of my application and its Cards]